# How can I get Expand Collapse Panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, drop-down-menu, expand

I need a small button and when I press it there should come up a panel with other content inside it. 
Here is example: https://gyazo.com/ce158edc3705191e2b733e2f37ea524f

I'm using windows form application.
Maybe I should go WPF ?

Comment: It's unclear what you need, a collapsible panel? a dropdown button which shows a menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently created a user control that was collapsible.  Taking some inspiration from here:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53318/C-Custom-Control-Featuring-a-Collapsible-Panel and other locations

Basically you add this control onto your form, then attach a panel which should contain all of your subcontrols.  Then you assign the Panel control to it like this;

```
 this.collapsibleControl1.LowerPanel = this.panel1;
```

This was just for some small personal project, so it is not tested a lot and might contain some problems.  But it should get your started.

Here is my usercontrol class:

```
public partial class CollapsibleControl : UserControl
{

    #region Declarations

    /// <summary>
    /// Declarations.
    /// </summary>
    private Control m_LowerPanel;
    private int FixedHeight = 150;
    private int CollapsibleIntervalValue = 2;
    private int HeaderHeightValue = 20;

    public delegate void CollapsedStateChangedEventHanlder(ControlState controlState);
    public event CollapsedStateChangedEventHanlder CollapsedStateChanged;

    public enum ControlState { Collapsed, Expanded}
    private ControlState _controlCollaspedState = ControlState.Expanded;

    #endregion

    #region Initialize

    public CollapsibleControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Collapsible properties

    [Description("The collasped state of the control, collasped or expanded"), Category("Collapsible Control"), DefaultValueAttribute(ControlState.Expanded)]
    public ControlState ControlCollaspedState
    {
        get { return _controlCollaspedState; }
        set
        {
            this._controlCollaspedState = value;
            DoCollapsible();
        }
    }

    [Description("The test to show at the top of the control"), Category("Collapsible Control")]
    public String DisplayText
    {
        get { return this.lblTop.Text; }
        set { this.lblTop.Text = value; }
    }

    [Description("The background color of the text box"), Category("Collapsible Control"), DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Window")]
    public Color TextBackgroundColor
    {
        get { return this.lblTop.BackColor; }
        set { this.lblTop.BackColor = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [Description("The panel which will be minimized"), Category("Collapsible Control")]
    public Control LowerPanel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.m_LowerPanel;
        }
        set
        {
            this.m_LowerPanel = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets/Sets CollapsibleInterval
    /// </summary>
    [Description("The interval determining how long it takes to open and close"), Category("Collapsible Control"), DefaultValueAttribute(2)]
    public int CollapsibleInterval
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CollapsibleIntervalValue;
        }
        set
        {
            this.CollapsibleIntervalValue = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// setting values for Header height
    /// </summary>
    [Description("The height of the header"), Category("Collapsible Control"), DefaultValueAttribute(20)]
    public int HeaderHeight
    {
        get
        {
            return this.HeaderHeightValue;
        }
        set
        {
            this.HeaderHeightValue = value;
            this.lblTop.Height = this.HeaderHeightValue;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Method for Collapsible animation.
    /// </summary>
    private void DoCollapsible()
    {
        if (this.m_LowerPanel == null || this.lblTop == null)
            return;

        //if expanded
        if (this.m_LowerPanel.Height > this.lblTop.Height)
        {
            FixedHeight = this.m_LowerPanel.Height;

            while (this.m_LowerPanel.Height > this.lblTop.Height)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
                this.m_LowerPanel.Height -= CollapsibleIntervalValue;
            }
            this.lblTop.ImageIndex = 1;
            this.m_LowerPanel.Height = 0;
            //this.ControlCollaspedState = ControlState.Collapsed;
        }
        else if (this.m_LowerPanel.Height < this.lblTop.Height)  //if collapsed
        {
            int x = this.FixedHeight;
            while (this.m_LowerPanel.Height <= (x))
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
                this.m_LowerPanel.Height += CollapsibleIntervalValue;
            }
            this.lblTop.ImageIndex = 0;
            this.m_LowerPanel.Height = x;
            //this.ControlCollaspedState = ControlState.Expanded;
        }

        if (this.CollapsedStateChanged != null)
            CollapsedStateChanged(this.ControlCollaspedState);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// CollapsiblePanel usercontrol load event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void  CollapsibleControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.FixedHeight = this.Height;
        this.lblTop.Height = this.HeaderHeightValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// click event for Collapsible image.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void lblTop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoCollapsible();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// setting values to label width when resizing the control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void CollapsibleControl_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.lblTop.Width = this.Width;
    }     
}
```